# Load balancer SQLAlchemy connections between multiple URLs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been searching on the SQLAlchemy documentation about a possibility to register multiple URLs and let SQLAlchemy handle the connection (timeout, fallback, load balancing), but I couldn't find anything related to it.

Is there a way to setup SQLAlchemy in that way, or do I have to do this on my end by creating multiple engines ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4392

Comment: Thank you for that. It might be a solution, but it needs to be able to handle between read and write (often, there is one master and a few slaves having read access only, this would need to be present on sqlalchemy too). I don't think the Github link would handle that.